# Java REST service to download file from AWS S3

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

Can some one help me understand this:
When I deploy my REST service in EC2 server and if the EC2 server has IAM role for S3 access, it will download file from S3.
What if I am working on my dev/ local environment and trying to access file from S3. I came to know that we need to use, Amazon CLI to access S3 from local environment.
Can some one explain how my Java code will check for credentials in Amazon CLI(installed in my Mac) to access S3?

Answer (score 0):

When you set up AWS CLI access, you create a folder in your local user's folder called .aws, in here there is a credentials file which your locally executing java code will look for. It's called the [default credential provider chain](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html).

First off it will look at your systems environment variables, if there's no credentials there, it will look at your java system properties. If it's not there, it will look at `~/.aws/credentials`, etc. Eventually, as the last option it will look at the EC2 Instance profile credentials, which is the IAM role you have granted to the EC2 Instance you're running the code on.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html), this is the order that the AWS SDK for Java looks for credentials in your system:

1. Environment variables – AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY.
2. Java system properties – aws.accessKeyId and aws.secretKey.
3. The default credential profiles file – typically located at
   ~/.aws/credentials
4. Amazon ECS container credentials (not relevant to your question).
5. Instance profile credentials (not relevant to your question).

When you run `aws configure` to configure the AWS CLI during the first usage, your credentials are saved to ~/.aws/credentials, so, it should just work, as long as you already have access to S3 using the CLI.